# How do I Incorporate Lists into my Scratch Game?

Tags: mit-scratch

I want to incorporate a list for my tycoon game, but I do not know how. I tried a lot of ways and failed each time. How can I incorporate a list into my scratch.mit.edu cash tycoon game? I am thinking of having an investment feature but I do not know how to use a list for something like that. I attached an image of my current code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbjmo.png

Answer (score 1):

have three lists:

1. a list of all investment options(names)
2. a list of their price incressis(the same order as the first list)
3. a list on what investments you have(the names)

repeat every ? seconds:
now loop over the last list and based off of the item number of the first list add $ based off the second one

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 1 and 2?

Comment: the first and second list ^

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure how I would go about doing what you said for 1 and 2 and I do not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: okay so in the start of the post i have a list of all the list's you need in you project

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to write it (`scratchblocks` format):

```
[scratchblocks]
forever
add (foo) to [list1 v]
...
add (foo1) to [list2 v]
...
add (foo2) to [list3 v]
...
end
[\scratchblocks]
```

Here's an image:

[image]

The `foo`, `foo1`, and `foo2` operators here are defined as:

| `foo` | `foo1` | `foo2` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adding the list of all of the investment options that there are in your tycoon game | The list of their increasing prices (which would be in the same order as which `foo` is defined | The list of the investments that you currently own (doesn't necessarily have to be in the same order as `foo`/`foo1`) |

Hope this helps!